# how we can overlay a layout on Image View

Tags: android, android-imageview

how we can overlay a layout with TextViews and Buttons over an image in ImageView with respect to x and y co-ordinates of the image

Comment: Just Declare specification of your question'

Answer (score 0):

always a good resource for android and layouts is this: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/. The respective `layout_x` and `layout_y` can also be set programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout as the main container and place all your elements inside using margins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="A text" 
        />

</FrameLayout>
```